# How can I make sure the IMXML gets included in an Actionscript project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using Flex Builder for an Actionscript which apparently has a dependency on IMXML object. I'd never heard of this object, and there is nothing on the project site about any dependencies. I assume it's a Flex component library, though. Which library should I include in order for this program to resolve its dependency issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a Flex Project or an ActionScript project?  How do you know the project has a dependency to the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the core Flex SDK.  (`mx.core`)  If it's missing - check your SDK path, something's probably gone screwy there.  You should have (amongst others) `flex.swc` and `framework.swc` present.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have those on my sdk path. Can I get just those files separately? I'd hate to have to reinstall the whole program.

Comment: Grad the SDK from here:  http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK.  The files you're after should be in there.